# 'import' scope and specify path?

Tags: maven, maven-3

We have a pom file that specifies all our common dependencies ([a BOM file](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/02/18/maven-bom-bill-of-materials-dependency/)), that is imported as follows:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.myproduct</groupId>
            <artifactId>external-modules-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

It is possible to specify a system path for the pom file so that it does not need to be present in the maven repository?  It seems that `systemPath` can only be used when using `system` scope, and then the BOM isn't imported properly.  Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of doing that if you want to use built-in `import` scope, what I strongly recommend in your case.

Of course, probably you will be able to find some hacky combination of 3rd party plugins that effectively give you what you want, but I believe Maven is all about convention over configuration and you should prefer standard solutions to keep it simple and readable.

BTW, under the cover `import` scope does actually copy and paste the `pom` dependency of that scope, after basic syntax processing. The dependency resolution here is the standard one.

Comment: I was worried that might be the case Michal.  I'd prefer a "legit" maven solution rather than depending on exotic 3rd party plugins to so it (for the same reasons as you suggest). I was considering a repository definition that pointed to where the BOM file is, but I'm not sure if that's better or not.

Comment: IMHO repo is always OK (unless it is `file://`).